# Detecting disconnect using mq-jms-spring from IBM

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am trying to write a health check for our JMS connection that connects to MQ using IBM JMS integrations code [ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring). I need to detect that the connection to MQ has been lost. I hooked the exceptionListener for the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory and that tells me when I lose the connection to MQ but I cannot find anything in the JMS stack that tells me when the connection gets (re)established.

Code that calls the ExceptionListener

```
    @Override
protected void establishSharedConnection() {
    try {
        super.establishSharedConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
            invokeExceptionListener((JMSException) ex);
        }
        logger.debug("Could not establish shared JMS Connection - " +
                "leaving it up to asynchronous invokers to establish a Connection as soon as possible", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a strictly JMS perspective, when the `onException` method of your `ExceptionListener` is invoked it is up to your application to re-establish the JMS connection using `ConnectionFactory.createConnection`. This is a blocking call so once it returns successfully then you know the connection has been re-established.

If you're delegating the JMS connection management to Spring it's unlikely you will be able to be informed about when the JMS connection is re-established. I don't see any hooks in  Spring JMS for this.

Comment: Update your question with the code - don't post it in the comments.

Comment: I don't see how it is expecting me to try to reconnect.

Comment: It's not expecting you to try to reconnect because you've delegated the JMS connection management to Spring so you no longer have the level of control that you would if you were using straight JMS. Spring can be useful in many scenarios, but it takes fine-grained control away from your application so it can also be limiting in certain use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I have observed last week is that if MQ is coded or configured to use the reconnect functionality then an ExceptionListener receives a message from the queue manager when a reconnection is made.